# Flutter firebase-admob check if rewarded video is loading

Tags: firebase, flutter, admob

Using flutter and this plugin (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_admob),

**How can I check if the Rewarded video is load?**

I received this Exception :

```
PlatformException(ad_not_loaded, show failed for rewarded video, no ad was loaded, null)
```

but i can't capture it.

Thank you.

Comment: Seems like a known issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25022, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26971

Answer (score 8):

You need to use the await keyword

```dart
 void showRewardedAd() async {
    try {
      await RewardedVideoAd.instance.load(
          adUnitId: RewardedVideoAd.testAdUnitId, targetingInfo: targetingInfo);

      await RewardedVideoAd.instance.show();
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
    }
  }
```

and on your listener method add below lines

```
 if (event == RewardedVideoAdEvent.loaded) {
        setState(() {
         isRewardADLoaded = true;
        });
      }
```

Comment: is it necessary to wrap isRewardADLoaded = true; inside setState?

Comment: is it better to move RewardedVideoAd.instance.load() into initState? and only try show()